# Event Waitlist - Paid

Tags: waitlist

Is possible to set a limit of say 20 participants for an event, have waitlist enabled and when people register for waitlist, they still have to pay like a normal registration?

I couldn't see that and hope I haven't missed it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is without custom code :-(

The idea of the waitlist is they only pay if they have a place.

Answer (score 1):

For your case I think you could instead use the pending approval functionality. That way a real-time payment is made but you can make the registration final.